# Failed to install a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04, and I'm trying to use this [project](https://github.com/orelzion/Grape_on_rack_sqlite3).

I understand that I first need to install its dependencies, but when I try  to install the Grape gem I'm getting this error

```
ERROR:  Error installing grape:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I pretty new to Ruby at all, so I'll appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: What ruby version are you running?

Comment: ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: It looks like you might have to use ruby 1.9.3 with that project, as it lists it it's gemfile. Are you using a ruby version manager?

Comment: Well you're really going to have to learn what that is and you're going to need to use it.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev` and retry installing gem

Comment: Alright, so I installed ruby 1.9.1 and now it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: I highly recommend using https://rvm.io/ or http://www.rubyinside.com/rbenv-a-simple-new-ruby-version-management-tool-5302.html to manage your ruby versions and ruby gems.

Answer (score 0):

A devel is missing, please install it, ans it will work right away:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```